SwiftUI .onAppear wont trigger when @Environment changes
I'm trying to convert all my @EnvironmentObject to @Environment and I ran into an issue. The UserService has a property user which is nil. After that a network call takes place and the user gets updated. These changes get published in the View but unlike before, .onAppear() is not triggered again. I need this because once I have the user I need to call a method in the ViewModel which needs the user.
This used to work fine before but I guess something under the hood must have changed. Is there a new way to handle this?
@Observable class UserService {
    var user: User?
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        print("UserService int()")
    }
    
    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            self.getCurrentUser(uid: user?.uid)
        })
    }
    
    func getCurrentUser(uid: String?) {
        guard let uid = uid else { return }
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
            do {
                self.user = try documentSnapshot?.data(as: User.self)
                print("getCurrentUser", self.user?.displayName)
            } catch {
                print("error")
                self.error = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DiscoverView: View {
    @Environment(UserService.self) private var userService
    
    var body: some View {
        // OK gets updated when user is updated
        Text(userService.user?.displayName ?? "nil")
            .onAppear() {
                print("onAppear")
                if userService?.user {
                    //trigger something else 
                }
                // will trigger once and wont trigger when user is updated
            }
    }
}


The fact that onAppear is only called once in your case is actually the correct behavior and how it should be.
Only if the (structural) identity of a SwiftUI view were to change would onAppear also be called multiple times. A change to a state of a view does not result in multiple calls to onAppear.
To observe the change of User in your case, the correct way would be to use onChange:
Text(userService.user?.displayName ?? "nil")
    .onChange(of: userService.user) { oldUser, newUser in
        print("User changed: \(newUser?.displayName)")
    }
    .onAppear() {
        print("onAppear")
    }

If onAppear was called multiple times in your old code, this could actually indicate a problem with your view hierarchies and the SwiftUI state handling.
The use of conditional view modifiers, for example, can lead to this issue.

It makes sense actually thats why its called on appear. I was doing something wrong. I get this error actually Referencing instance method 'onChange(of:initial:_:)' on 'Optional' requires that 'User' conform to 'Equatable'. Is it because var user: User? shouldn't be an optional?

User needs to conform to Equatable for onChange to work because the closure will only be called when the value actually changes. And without the Equatable conformance, SwiftUI would not be able to recognize whether a value has changed. It is not a problem that the user property is optional.
